# cassandra read query time analysis

Tags: cassandra, timeout

We are using cassandra-3.0.15. A few of the read queries takes longer time(>500ms). Based on the query tracing it seems the co-ordinator node takes a longer time than expected especially while starting to process the request. What could be the reason for that? How to solve this issue?

Have attached the query trace for one of the such requests below. It can be seen that the first activity "Executing single-partition query on facility_configuration" takes around 1.4sec. The rest of the activities are pretty fast.

```
activity                                                                  | source         | source_elapsed | thread
---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------

   Executing single-partition query on facility_configuration | node1 |        1466289 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Acquiring sstable references                               | node1 |        1466298 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Key cache hit for sstable 6                                | node1 |        1466314 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | node1 |        1466330 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables                 | node1 |        1466341 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells                          | node1 |        1466450 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   reading digest from /node2                                 | node1 |        1466466 |                       SharedPool-Worker-6

   Sending READ message to /node2                             | node1 |        1467388 |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/node2

   READ message received from /node1                          | node2 |              1 | MessagingService-Incoming-/node1

   Executing single-partition query on facility_configuration | node2 |            536 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Acquiring sstable references                               | node2 |            546 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Key cache hit for sstable 6                                | node2 |            562 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | node2 |            575 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables                 | node2 |            586 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells                          | node2 |            642 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells                          | node2 |            807 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Enqueuing response to /node1                               | node2 |            819 |                       SharedPool-Worker-3

   Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /node1                 | node2 |            845 | MessagingService-Outgoing-/node1

   REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /node2              | node1 |        1470583 |  MessagingService-Incoming-/node2

   Processing response from /node2                            | node1 |        1470665 |                      SharedPool-Worker-15

session_id                           | client       | command | coordinator    | duration | parameters                                                                                 | request                     | started_at
--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------

ddef2100-eb53-11e9-86ed-9d59234ed651 | clientNode |   QUERY | node1 |  1470765 | {'consistency_level': 'QUORUM', 'page_size': '5000', 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL'} | Execute CQL3 prepared query | 2019-10-10 11:48:24+0000

facility_configuration histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                           (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             1.00              0.00            182.79               124                 5
75%             1.00              0.00            263.21               258                 7
95%             2.00              0.00            545.79              1597                14
98%             2.00              0.00            943.13              1597                14
99%             2.00              0.00           1358.10              1597                14
Min             0.00              0.00             51.01                87                 5
Max             2.00              0.00           1955.67              1597                14

tablestats
 Read Count: 68390050
 Read Latency: 0.08643708858233032 ms.
 Write Count: 11
 Write Latency: 0.09781818181818182 ms.
 Pending Flushes: 0
     Table: facility_configuration
     SSTable count: 2
     Space used (live): 12241
     Space used (total): 12241
     Space used by snapshots (total): 0
     Off heap memory used (total): 103
     SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.5963017053887002
     Number of partitions (estimate): 7
     Memtable cell count: 0
     Memtable data size: 0
     Memtable off heap memory used: 0
     Memtable switch count: 4
     Local read count: 68390066
     Local read latency: 0.195 ms
     Local write count: 11
     Local write latency: NaN ms
     Pending flushes: 0
     Bloom filter false positives: 0
     Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
     Bloom filter space used: 40
     Bloom filter off heap memory used: 24
     Index summary off heap memory used: 55
     Compression metadata off heap memory used: 24
     Compacted partition minimum bytes: 87
     Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1597
     Compacted partition mean bytes: 420
     Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
     Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
     Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
     Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some info around the partitions, namely run `nodetool tablestats <ks>.<cf>` and `nodetool tablehistograms <ks> <cf>` on the node that is taking longest to response (node2).

Comment: @LyubenTodorov I have just added both histograms and tablestats as part of my query above.